# Mariadb Innodb Recovering data from a bad "hot" copy with .frm .ibd ib_logfile and ibdata

Tags: linux, mariadb, innodb

I have a server that is up and running with everything I need except for two tables that were truncated.

Our backup process seems to have never been tested or was only ever tested with myisam tables. It essentially boils down to this:

```
echo "Backing up $backup_files to $dest/$archive_file"
tar czf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files
```

And I'm guessing it was never tested with innodb tables. The server is not stopped before these commands are ran, and in my replication of the issue things actually would work fine if the server were stopped first, the commands were ran, and then the server was restarted. The problem is the data I need to recover is from the time period with this bad "hot" copy is all I have.

If I try to run the hot copy, the mariadb server will not start. systemctl status mariadb.service returns:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: core-dump) since Sun 2021-02-07 00:26:55 EST; 1s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 22374 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22371 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27242 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
  Process: 26956 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26949 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26945 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27242 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
   Status: "Starting final batch to recover 179 pages from redo log"

Feb 07 00:26:55 wdb1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Feb 07 00:26:55 wdb1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.11 database server.
Feb 07 00:26:55 wdb1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 07 00:26:55 wdb1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

I've also set up a new server with a fresh install to see if I can recover just the two tables, but I'm running into similar issues starting it with copies of those files only and a few other steps.

On a fresh server I've tried to copy the contents of an error when I copy the "hot copy" of /var/lib/mysql in place of the "fresh" information.

```
cat /var/log/mysql/error.log
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Plugin 'unix_socket' already installed
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=953405634310
2021-02-07  6:29:02 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: is_short 0, info_and_status_bits 0, offset 2661, o_offset 6, mismatch index 18446744073709551582, end_seg_len 46 parsed len 3
210207  6:29:02 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu1
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467424 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x49000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x32)[0x560e258ad542]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x55d)[0x560e253eae9d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14bb0)[0x7f292571abb0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb)[0x7f292522d8cb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x116)[0x7f2925212864]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa5192c)[0x560e2568092c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4cafbf)[0x560e250f9fbf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9a6e13)[0x560e255d5e13]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9a7cb0)[0x560e255d6cb0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4c6c30)[0x560e250f5c30]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4ec9aa)[0x560e2511b9aa]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa9e3b1)[0x560e256cd3b1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa9e5d3)[0x560e256cd5d3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa8969a)[0x560e256b869a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x993983)[0x560e255c2983]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xaa1f48)[0x560e256d0f48]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4df2f6)[0x560e2510e2f6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x95e438)[0x560e2558d438]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x70)[0x560e253ed5f0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5eb1f6)[0x560e2521a1f6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x88e)[0x560e2521b32e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x524c04)[0x560e25153c04]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x401)[0x560e2515a801]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf2)[0x7f2925214cb2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x2e)[0x560e2514d70e]
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             62387                62387                processes
Max open files            96384                96384                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       62387                62387                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Core pattern: |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course right after I post here I find a working solution.

Fresh server.

Copy the hot copy over all the files in /var/lib/mysql.

```
rm -R ib_logfile*
```

Then the fresh server will restart normally and even have data in the relevant tables I happened to care about.